# how do I detect download in progress using c#?

Tags: c#, networking, download

how do I detect download in progress (in any application such as download in IE or firefox or download manager ) using c#?

Comment: What do you consider a download?

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much impossible IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could hope for is some sort of packet monitor that ties the packets to a particular process ID. Even given that, you wouldn't be very well able to track an individual download, but rather the entire throughput of a single process (each packet of data coming in or out).

Comment: yeah, and that would bring the problem what traffic to consider to be a download + doing some kind of hooking in c# of `winsock` is some kind of `high flight` code, it's more easy to mess with that in C

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTPAnalyzer, you should be able to infer this to certain extent - but this will be a manual process. May be u can use some some of its exposed API to automate.

BTW why do you need this - is there a practical scenario where this is really required?

Comment: i have a desktop application which logs out user automatiocally after 15 min of in activity. if any download in progress during the idle period my application logs out automatically without considering download